# Share unix-domain sockets between namespaces created by "ip netns"?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-namespaces

Is it possible to share unix-domain sockets between namespaces created by `ip netns`?

My default namespace is connected to an internal network.  I have a namespace named `inet`, which has access to the internet.    I'd like to run a browser in the `inet` namespace and connect to it via VNC from the internal network.   But the problem is that that the connection from the browser to the VNC server is a unix domain socket, which is technically a form of networking.   Since the browser and the X11/VNC server are in different network namespaces, they can't communicate.

Is there any way to share unix domain sockets between two network namespaces?

```
$ netstat --unix -lpn| grep X11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     31239    3247/Xtigervnc       /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     31238    3247/Xtigervnc       @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1

$ ip netns
inet (id: 0)

$ sudo ip netns exec inet  netstat --unix -lpn
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path

$ sudo ip netns exec inet  sh -c 'DISPLAY=:1 xmessage foo'
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :1
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix domain sockets are not affected by your network namespace. If we create two namespaces:

```
ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2
```

And then create a unix socket in one:

```
ip netns exec ns1 socat unix-listen:/tmp/mysocket -
```

We can connect to that from another namespace without a problem:

```
ip netns exec ns2 socat - unix-connect:/tmp/mysocket
```

And communicate just fine. Unix sockets are bound to the filesystem, not the network environment (this fact is often used to communicate between containers by placing unix sockets on a shared volume).

---

Furthermore, on my system, we see:

```
$ netstat --unix -lpn |grep X11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     100157   11744/Xorg           @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     100158   11744/Xorg           /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
```

And also:

```
$ sudo ip netns exec ns1 netstat --unix -lpn
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
$
```

But this works just ifne:

```
$ sudo ip netns exec ns1 sh -c 'DISPLAY=:1 xmessage foo'
```

Comment: Was this always the case? I remember having problems.

Comment: It looks like this has been the case since 2010, see [this patch](https://lore.kernel.org/all/4C1733BE.6070708@openvz.org/T/).

Comment: Fun fact: the ioctl `SIOCGSKNS` returns the network namespace the unix domain socket is associated with; this was set to the network namespace the caller was attached to when creating the unix domain socket.